# Как определить приоритет листания для двух разнонаправленных RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-viewpager

Есть два `RecyclerView` - один горизонтальный со списком экранов (взамен `ViewPager` грубо говоря), второй вертикальный со списком тех или иных элементов.

При строго вертикальном листании (когда dX при MotionEvent крайне мал, или угол первоначального движения равен 0/180 градусов (где 0 - верх, 180 - соответственно низ)) проблем не возникает и "листается" именно нужный вертикальный `RecyclerView` с элементами "вложенный" в горизонтальный. Но при малейшем отклонении при старте листания на несколько градусов (буду честен - не замерял, но визуально, уже более 10 градусов проблемы) листается горизонтальный `RecyclerView` и происходит дальнейшее перелистывание страницы на другую.

Каким образом можно решить данную проблем? Как либо определить "приоритет" листания или же определить абстрактно минимальный угол, после которого начинается листаться внешний-горизонтальный `RecyclerView`. Возможно кто то сталкивался с данной проблемой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня в целом ситуация схожая:

1. Есть `ScrollView`, который отвечает за вертикальный скроллинг
2. При этом каждая страничка уложена в `PagerFragment` в котором реализован горизонтальный свайп

Я честно, не задумывался о существовании такой проблемы: приоритетах свайпов, пока не увидел вопрос ТС. Кстати, до сих пор не уверен, что проблема прямо уж так актуальна, соответственно не уверен, что буду ее решать в своем приложении.

Но если в один прекрасный день все таки начну решать, то очевидно буду решать ее так:

1. Создам собственные классы `MyScrollView` и `MyPagerFragment`
2. Переопределю в них методы `onInterceptTouchEvent()`, в которых буду определять новые `GestureListener`, которые будут определять наличие отсутствие жеста в зависимости от координат жеста - [примерно как указано в документации](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html)

Ни разу не делал этого и не уверен, что буду делать, но отправная точка будет именно такая.

Comment: Мотивация перехода от fragment'ов и viewpager'a это отдельный разговор. Реализовал я двумя способами - указанный вами выше (с SimpleOnGestureListener) и более сложным с вычислениями, учитывающий scaledTouchSlop. По скорости и простоте работы оказался GestureListener в приоритете.

Comment: Если соберусь реализовывать - обязательно воспользуюсь вашим опытом.